# improve mysql query performance, full text search

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have two tables - `posts` and `comments`. Using **MySQL full-text** search I need to find posts and comments that match some entered text. For an each post I need to find also 0-3(3 can be changed to 5 or more) comments. Also, I'd like to have a pagination by posts.

Right now I have a following query:

```
SELECT score_comment + score_post AS score_sum, temp.* FROM (
SELECT t_1.*,
      @num := IF(@post_id = post_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
      @post_id := post_id AS dummy
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MATCH (comm.content) AGAINST ("standart server web detected") AS score_comment, paged_post.*,
  comm.comment_id, comm.last_edited AS c_last_edited, comm.content FROM comments AS comm
INNER JOIN
(SELECT *,
 MATCH (description) AGAINST ("standart server web detected") AS score_post
    FROM posts
    WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ("standart server web detected") > 0
    LIMIT 0, 10) AS paged_post 
ON comm.post_id = paged_post.post_id
WHERE MATCH (comm.content) AGAINST ("standart server web detected") > 0) AS comm_view ORDER BY post_id, c_last_edited DESC) AS t_1
) AS temp WHERE temp.row_number <=3
ORDER BY score_comment + score_post DESC;
```

Looks like this query is doing a right job but I'm worried about performance. Right now on my home machine for 10k posts and 500k comments it works approximately 2.1 -2.2 seconds

Is there any way to improve this query in order to decrease the execution time ?